# IIS Blue / Green deployment wrong sites started after reboot

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10, blue-green-deployment

We setup our IIS sites to accommodate blue / green deployments. We noticed that after reboot the wrong sites get started.

The setup:

`app.blue`
`app.green`
`app.entry`

On the `app.entry` site we have a rewrite rule that forwards traffic to either the `app.blue` or `app.green` depending on which is the active site. This all works as expected and has for quite some time.

Recently, because of Windows Updates the server has rebooted during non-production hours. After the reboot we noticed the wrong IIS sites are getting started. So, for example app.blue was the active site and the rewrite rule is pointing to `app.blue` on the `app.entry` rule. After the reboot, `app.green` is started, but obviously the entry rule is pointing to blue.

We are using the [IIS Admin API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/) to manage the site swaps and updating the rewrite rule. What seems to be strange is the sites that get started were set as the previous Blue / Green site. In the example above, `app.green` was the previous site so after reboot it gets restarted and the `app.blue` was stopped.

The only option I can think of to correct this is to has a task run after reboot to check the rewrite rules and start / stop the correct sites.